# Is it possible in taskwarrior for reminders about recurring tasks to expire automatically?

Tags: taskwarrior

I'm using taskwarrior. I want to be reminded of something every week, but have that reminder go away automatically if I haven't completed it by the time the next week comes up. (Or, actually, I want the task to be due on Tuesday, and vanish if I don't get it done by Friday afternoon, because I'm not going to bother on the weekends and at that point it's just gonna wait for the next one.)

I know how to [set up recurring tasks](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1153638), but there, the `until` applies to how long the weekly reminders will be generated. I want the generated weekly reminders *themselves* to expire. Is this possible?

Comment: This is a recurring task that is due say each week, and you want it to go away if it isn't completed?

Comment: @slm Yeah. I want it to show up in my "here's what you should be working on" report, but if I miss it, it's no big deal.

Comment: To help you debug this further, could you provide an example of what you currently have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, no, Taskwarrior doesn't support this flavor of recurring task yet.  It's planned, but currently only hard-deadline, non-expiring tasks are supported.

Soon there should be expiring recurring tasks, and also ones that becomes due a set time after the previous one, rather than on a hard schedule.

Disclosure: I am affiliated with the Taskwarrior project.

Comment: How do you know this?  Are you involved in developing Taskwarrior?  Can you point us to a reference?

Comment: I wrote most of it.  Here's an issue that links to other related issues: https://bug.tasktools.org/browse/TW-1284

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for sharing your knowledge with Stack Exchange.  I asked for two reasons: (1) to “vet” your answer, so people will know why they should believe it, and (2) because of Stack Exchange policy.  If you write about a product/project that you’re associated with, you are required to disclose your relationship to it.  See [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) (the last section) and [How to not be a spammer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).